# Local/Offline Development using AWS ElastiCache for Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, redis, amazon-elasticache

I need to do local/offline development using AWS ElastiCache for Redis. I checked LocalStack but the open source Community Edition do not provide this feature. You can refer the pricing model [here](https://localstack.cloud/pricing/).
Is there any other alternative for local/offline development using AWS ElastiCache for Redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticache is just hosted Redis; you don't need anything special for development, just a local copy of Redis (in a container if you'd like).

Comment: If we implement Redis without ElastiCache then there will be code changes right when we move the application to production as in production there will be ElastiCache with Redis

Comment: Aside from the host name, it's not really different.  The same code base works with plain Redis for local development, Redis in a container for integration testing, and Elasticache Redis; the only thing that needs to be configured is the host name.

Comment: AWS is using their own implementation. As of May 2022 there is e.g. JSON support in the AWS offering: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/unlocking-json-workloads-with-elasticache-and-memorydb/